Swagger JWT SecurityScheme not working while running the JAR, but works in Intellij IDE
I have a spring boot application that uses JWT tokens and I have setup OpenAPI definitions and Security Scheme to provide documentation.  When running the spring boot application on the IDE, the swagger documentation include the bearer authentication lock as seen below.  I have no external configuration and everything is included in the jar.
Now, if I just run the jar, using java -jar myApplication.jar, it doesn't show the lock symbol on the swagger documentation. Everything else seems to be fine.  In IntelliJ my run configuration is Application.

